# При переходе из одного модального окна в другое, появляется scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css3, bootstrap

При закрытии одного модального окна в другое атрибутом (data-dismiss="modal"), во втором модальном окне появляется Scroll

```css
.card-card {
  border: 1px solid #d3d9de;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}

.card-t {
  border-top: 1px solid #d3d9de;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.card-h {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.buttons {
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.card-h img {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>



     <div class="container-fluid content-card">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card-card">
         <div class="card-h" align="center">
         </div>
         <div class="card-t">
          <p align="center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600;">Диагностика</p>
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#diagnostics">Подробнее</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       
       
       
           <div class="modal fade" id="diagnostics">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
        
          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;">Диагностика ноутбука / компьютера</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Modal body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="button-close" align="center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#call">Заказать звонок</button>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Modal footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
        <div class="modal fade" id="call">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
        
          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;">Обратная связь</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Modal body -->
          <div class="modal-body">



           <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">


            <div class="messages"></div>
             <div class="controls">
              
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="form_name">Имя <red>*</red></label>
                 <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше имя" required="required" data-error="Укажите имя.">
                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="form_email">Email</label>
                 <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Не обязательно">
                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="form_phone">Контактный номер <red>*</red></label>
                 <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш контактный номер" required="required" data-error="Укажите контактный номер.">
                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="form_message">Заметка </label>
                 <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Опишите вашу проблему или предложение" rows="4"></textarea>
                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-12">
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Отправить">
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>



           </form>




          </div>
          
          <!-- Modal footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>






    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Если развернуть результат Вашего кода на весь экран, то у меня не появляется. Chrome.

Comment: В примере не появляется. Проблема явно не в этом коде

Comment: @РашенБеар
Пример можно увидеть на сайте test.expertpc.by

Comment: @Дмытрык Пример можно увидеть на сайте test.expertpc.by

Answer (score 0):

Во время открытия 2-го диалогового окна, не нужно менять класс `body`. Из-за этого у `body` меняется значение атрибута `overflow`, с `hidden` на `visible`. Либо же нужно не менять, а добавлять класс `modal-open`.

В данный момент, при переходе с 1-го окна на 2-е у него класс меняется c `modal-open` на `style`.

Comment: Таки я тоже замечал что при открытии второго модального окна отсутствует класс ".modal-open", только вот не пойму сейчас как поправить.

Comment: Надо знать, какой код меняет эти классы